# HTML / PHP / SQL - Why won't my form updates submit if my form values are pre-set?

Tags: php, forms, post, sql-update, submit

I'm currently working on a blog website made in PHP, and I'm trying to make a form to update a pre-existing blogpost. Since it's an update I want the form to be pre-filled with the old content when I open it, so I've set the value to variables that contain the title and content of the post I'm editing. The problem is that when this value is set, if I press submit the edited text does not get passed into the database, it still passes in the same value I start with. The sql query should be fine cause if I open the form without the values set I can overwrite the blog post in question without any issue. I'm thinking it may be the $_POST variable that does not update at the right time and grabs the pre-set value instead of what gets typed in. How do I fix this?

**Here's the post function:**

```
  if (isset ($_POST['btn-post'])){
//getting rid of whitespace
    $title     = trim($_POST['title']);
    $content   = trim($_POST['content']);
    $ID = $postID;
   // $tags      = trim($_POST['tags']);

if (empty ($title)){

        $error[] = "Please enter a title."; 
    }

    if (empty($content)) {

        $error[] = "Please enter some text.";
    } 

    if (strlen($title) > 250) {
    $errors = 'Please shorten your title, it is too long (250 character limit).';
    }

    if (strlen($content) > 2000) {
    $errors = 'Please shorten your blog post, it is too long (2000 character limit).';
    }

    else {
        $post->updatePost($title, $content, $ID);
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit;
    }
}
```

**Here's the query:**

```
    public function updatePost($title,$content,$postID)
{
   try
   {$stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE posts
                                SET post_title = :post_title, post_content = :post_content
                                WHERE post_id=:post_id");

       $stmt->bindParam(":post_title", $title);
       $stmt->bindParam(":post_content", $content);
       $stmt->bindParam(":post_id", $postID);  
       $stmt->execute();

       return $stmt; 
   }
   catch(PDOException $e)
   {
       echo $e->getMessage();
   }    
}
```

**Here's the post form with the preset value ($postTitle and $postValue are defined in another file):**

```
 <form class ="col-sm-8 well well-lg" action="" method="post">



            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" value="<?= $postTitle ?>">
            </div>  

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="content"> Content </label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="content" rows="10"><?= $postContent ?></textarea>
            </div>

                <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Update Post" name="btn-post">
                </div>
                       </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Case closed - one of the variables was calling the wrong index in an array, and two form elements had ended up with the same name.

Comment: Ergo, no way we could've figured that out with just the info you gave. but good job on debugging yourself. Normally var_dump the variables would help solve the issues.

Comment: Still very new to this, sorry, will make sure to include the full code the next time I run into an issue. Thanks for trying, and have started using var_dump more!

Answer (score -1):

You should be binding your title and content the same way you bind your post_id. Also it's bindParam().

Comment: I did initially have them bound like that, it did not make a difference. I only changed them to this way to see if it would help, which it didn't. (I will change them back, just need this issue solved)

Comment: You need to output your actual script that calls these functions. do var_dump on these variables to see what output you have for them. You need to fix the function name and also get rid of the single quotes and bind them. Update your code.

Comment: I've updated my post with the bindParams etc. That's not the issue. The query works perfectly fine, the only time it doesn't work is when I don't start with an empty form. When the form inputs have a set value the $_POST variable does not seem to update with the new inputs in time to pass it into the query.

Comment: I can't debug your code by you telling me the problem. Need to see the actual output and your code. If you form is empty, wouldn't you be doing an insertion? You don't even show where you retrieve these $_POST variables. Need your front end form as well.